# Parcel: add content hash to html

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, build, parceljs

I have three files. `loader.js` would create an iframe that loads `content.html` which then loads `content.js`. I publish `loader.js` so other people can include it in their site, and content html and js are internal.

Now I want to add a content hash to content.html and content.js so I can add some agressive cache config to these files.

When I build html with `parcel build content.html`, I got `content.html` and `content.<hash>.js`. Is there a way to put build hash to `content.html` as well and also update `loader.js` to include hashed content.html url?

EDIT: I think I found it's impossible - there is open issue https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/4498

Comment: Here is an example. https://github.com/daisy1754/parcel-load-iframe

I have three files, loader.js, content.html and content.js. loader.js is the only file I shared with client. I want to get build output of loader.js, content.hash.html and content.hash.js. Currently content.html is not hashed.

Comment: ^ @Greg if you can take a look that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Never worked with parcel, but the [documentation](https://parceljs.org/production.html#file-naming-strategy) says:

> Entrypoints are never hashed

So your `content.html` will not be hashed, because it is entrypoint: `parcel build content.html`

Comment: maybe I should rephrase the question - can we make content.html not entry point? it's loaded via loader.js (with document.createElement("iframe")) so theoretically loader.js is the entry point

Comment: @Kazuki it seems to me, that we need some code examples from your side. But, maybe, other people will help you if they've faced the same problem.

Comment: here is example - see my comment above for details https://github.com/daisy1754/parcel-load-iframe

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to add it:

- add an id to one of the assets, for example a css file
- in javascript, harvest the href of the link
- harvest the hash using a regexp.
- inject hash where needed.

Example:

```html
    <link id="ui-styling" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/default/style.less">

    <script>
        var href = document.getElementById("ui-styling").getAttribute("href");
        var m = /\.([^.]+)\.css$/.exec(href);
        var hash = m[1];
        
        // use or inject hash elsewhere ...
    </script>
```